# how to add ng-keyup to rails text_field helper for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem figuring out how to add an ng-keyup to a rails text_field helper used with form_for. This `<%#= f.text_field :email, ngkeyup: "checkEmail()" %>` comes close but adding the dash in ngkeyup causes it to error out and trying to make it a string doesn't work.

I have (but this is obviously not working):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%#= f.text_field :email %>
  <%#= f.text_field :email, options: {ng-keyup:"checkEmail()"} %>
  <%#= f.text_field :email, {ng-keyup:"checkEmail()"} %>
  <%#= f.text_field :email, ng-keyup:"checkEmail()" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email,,ng-keyup:"checkEmail()" %>
  <div id='email-status'></div>
<% end %>
```

and would like

```
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" ng-keyup="checkEmail()">
```

I really just need to get the ng-keyup value in here.

thx for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running rails 4.0.1 this did the trick for me:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, "ng-keyup" => "checkEmail()" %>
```

There are many other cases in which Rails won't accept any other key-value syntax expect the one with the hashrocket.

Comment: usually things with dashes